# OverFeat paper questions: confused fast and accurate models

Tags: conv-neural-network, pooling

I am reading the OverFeat paper "[OverFeat: Integrated Recognition, Localization and Detection using Convolutional Networks]"

I am confused about these two models: fast model and accurate model. The two models got different archetectures.

1. In section 3.3 in the paper, it talked about resolution augmentation on the unpooled layer 5 so I guess it talked about the fast model as the fast model has conv layers until layer 5. But when it talked about total subsampling ratio (2x3x2x3) it is obviously the accurate model (we can deduced from the pool layers).
2. In appendix Table 5, from the calculation of input sizes until layer 5 I guess it talked about the accurate model which however has conv layer until layer 6, then how come the dense pooling operation or so-called resolution augmentation is still applied on layer 5 just as that fast model which has 5 layer conv layers?

I did not get any response from the OverFeat google discussion group, so I come here to try my luck. I attached the related tables for your information.

Thanks guys.

[image: Accurate model params]
[image: Dense pooling on Accurate model Layer 5]

Comment: i feel you , the point is the explanation is a little bit ugly as i have been studying this paper for several times, just to make things easier for you focus on the accurate version and assume that the last conv+pool layer is the 5th one, i have found some other tiny dependencies in the paper too, so just focus on the concept, dont worry about the numbers.